# Jquery script for pulling wordpress posts not working from within post content

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a website: http://www.theartofcake.ca

The previous developer has added some code for the "Products" section that goes like this:

```
$('.open-services-single').unbind('click');
$('.open-services-single').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target_url = $(this).attr('href');
    var $loader = $('#services-loader');
    $loader.fadeIn();
    $('.services.single-contents').slideUp(500);
    $('.services.single-contents').load( target_url + " #single", function(){
        $loader.fadeOut();
        $(this).slideDown(500);
        $(".services.single-contents #post-thumbnails").cycle({
            fx: 'fade',// name of transition effect (or comma separated names, ex: 'fade,scrollUp,shuffle')
            pause: 1,
            speed: 1000,  // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value)
            timeout: 2000// milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)
        });
        //rebind();
        close_detail();
    });

});
```

When the user clicks on one of the products, it slides out a section that displays information from the selected post. I am trying to add a link inside one of the posts that will open up one of the other products in its place.

For example, there is a link inside the "cakes" section that I'm linking to "confections".. I would like confections to replace the cakes section as if someone clicked directly on the confections image under products... I hope that makes sense..

I thought that simply adding the class of "open-services-single" to the link inside the post would do the trick, but it just seems to open to the single post on its own page no matter what... Unfortunately my java skills are comprised of copy and pasting snippets of code that I can only understand by context.

Any suggestions? Please let me know if I am missing information that you would need to help me with this.

Thanks in advance!
Celeste

Answer (score 0):

What is the full HTML of the link? Did you try:

```
<a class="open-services-single" href="http://theartofcake.ca/product/confections/">open confections</a>
```

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I tried.. not sure why it doesn't work - maybe because that portion of the information is being pulled is from a different page (post) in the site?

Answer (score 0):

The concept is, javascript function modified the default html behavior when it's called and that is why you can see all the slide down and effects.

but when the javascript load in the individual products, after the html loaded, there is no javascript function to do the modification. So it will still be doing its default action, open the new page.

I see you have a commented out function:  //rebind(); use it to process the loaded html, then it should work the way you wanted.